# What is Context-Only in QnA Maker?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

When I use QnA Maker , Ifound something named CONTEXT-ONLY . What is it used  for?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Context-Only is a part of the multi-turn feature for qna-maker. When a question in the qna maker is set to 'Context-Only', a user cannot ask that question and get the answer. It can only be 'asked' as part of the multi-turn flow:

[image: MultiTurn QnA image]

For example, I have a question called 'Shocked Pikachu!' in my qnamaker kb. If this wasn't a Context-Only, a customer could put in 'Shocked Pikachu!' and get the answer 'I'm so confused!'. But because it is Context-Only, the only way to reach this answer is to go through the first question ("What is a pokemon"), and click the "NOT FLUFFY!" follow up:

[image: QnAMaker Test]

Notice that 'Shocked Pikachu!' IS listed as question, but is not available to be asked. This is typically not a good idea, you really want your prompts to match the question. I did it to show that clicking 'NOT FLUFFY' lead to that question's answer.