# QnA maker Context Only does not work: Follow up question Is understood outside of contextual flow

Tags: azure-qna-maker

So I follow every step that the Microsoft Docs say and what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972178/what-is-context-only-in-qna-maker) person said on Stackoverflow. I make sure that I check the `Add Follow-up Prompt` add the Q and A, then I check the `Context Only` box. Once I do that I save and train my bot. When I go to test it, I put the `Context Only` Q in the test environment and it still shows even though it specifies that `Context-only (this follow-up will not be understood out of the contextual flow).`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have found the same thing

Comment: @billoverton read the answer I just post, there is a solution

Comment: Great, I will try this. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I contacted their support and it was an issue on their end. 
After talking with Microsoft they rolled out an update to fix this bug. 
Context only works as stated now.